# OnPageFinished() function for WebView not getting called on Katex MathView for Android?

Tags: android, katex

I used [this](https://github.com/lingarajsankaravelu/Katex/blob/master/katexmathview/src/main/java/katex/hourglass/in/mathlib/MathView.java) MathView which is derived from WebView but the `OnPageFinsihed()` function for webView does not get called in this case? I am loading a string from my database in this view.

```
final MathView mWebView=view.findViewById(R.id.mathViewExplanation);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
        "height:"+view.getMeasuredHeight(),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("WebView Progres:",mWebView.getProgress()+" ");

        MoveButton(view.findViewById(R.id.cardViewNext),convertPixelsToDp(view.getMeasuredHeight(),getContext()));
    }
});
```

I want to call the `MoveButton()` function when the page is loaded.